# Control width expand onClick while setInterval, js,html5

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I have setInterval problem. I made something similar to load bar. When I click mouse I fire expanding width of my block called loadBar1

```
// here preset of interval and loadbar...
var interval = 0;
createLoadBar1 = function() {
loadBar1 = {
    // another stuff
    width:0,
};

document.onclick = function (mouse) {
    interval = setInterval(expandLoadBar1, 60);
}
```

It's expands by the help of this function:

```
function expandLoadBar1() {
    if(loadBar1.width < 60) {
        loadBar1.width++;
    }
    if (loadBar1.width >= 60) {
        loadBar1.width = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

It's very simple above and works well when I click just once but I start having problems when I click more that one time by mouse clicking, it's logically cause the faster loadBar1.width expanding twice and after second or more mouse click the clearInterval for interval stops working and just continue raising expanding speed when I click more.

Comment: Well then don’t start another interval, if you have one running already …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to clear the interval when the user clicks:

```
document.onclick = function () {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(expandLoadBar1, 60);
}
```

Comment: It's just stops expands at all if I click more that 1 time, and every 2 or more click just adds 1 to loadBar1.width

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user clicks the button? Should the bar expand fully before they can click again?

Comment: Just do nothing and wait till loadBar1.width expand to 60px width and collided to 0px , and then if click again it will start the same

Comment: In that case disable the button.

Comment: I just changed function and It seems to work almost good, the Interval work well after a lot of clicks and speed is not increased:                      function expandLoadBar1() {
  if(loadBar1.width < button1.width) {
   loadBar1.width++;
  } else {
   loadBar1.width = 0;
   clearInterval(interval);
  }
}   And also add clear interval inside function as you typed. Thanks)